# Background service shown in notification bar but not responding to events

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-keypad

I am trying to make an app that responds to headphone click events. Whenever i press headphone button it broadcasts an intent and my service start running in background. But once I make any call whether headphones are attached or not, no intent for button press is broadcasted and simple music player app starts with button press which is the default functionality of headphone button. I am new with broadcast receivers and keyevents, so I am not able to figure out where I am wrong. Please advice how to solve this issue. This is my ForeverBroadcastReceiver.java file

```
    public class ForeverBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @TargetApi(24)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("ForeverServiceReceiver" ,"Inside broadcast Receiver");

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ForeverService.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager =    (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
       // alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,1000,100,pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Start Alarm SERVICE IS UP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

ForeverService.java class

```
 public class ForeverService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer player;
    public static boolean IS_SERVICE_RUNNING = false;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForeverService";
    public ForeverService() {
    }

    @Override
    //will get started when service will start
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      return START_STICKY; 
    }
    public void onCreate(){
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("My awesome app")
                .setContentText("Doing some work...")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1337, notification);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null; //because we dont want to bind service with the activity
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
       }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private Button start, stop;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        //start listening for button clicks
     }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        audioManager  = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(this, ForeverBroadcastReceiver.class));
}
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 123){
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permission granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permission has been denied or request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.foreeverservice">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".ForeverBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
                android:name=".ForeverService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```